# Keep mobile browser from showing elements outside body?

Tags: html, css

Im making a website where i have a square rotated 45deg in the top right corner, and some of it is outsite of the body. On  desktop you not able to see it, but when i go on mobile i can zoom out and the right site of the body just gets bigger.

The red is what you able to see on you screen and this is how it looks on desktop and how i want it to look on mobile device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smrnt.jpg

But on mobile it looks like this, again where the red is what you able to see

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBwKJ.jpg

I got overflow-x hidden on body, so theres no scrollbar but the user is still able to zoom out and see the site like the second picture on mobile device.

I tried with meta tag, but its not really making any different, except that the site starts zoomed in, but user still able to zoom out.
like:

Html

```
<body class="bg">
    <div id="box-top-right">
        <a href="#">SOME TEXT</a>
     </div>
 <div id="wrapper">
 </div>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
 }

.bg {
background: url('../gfx/bg.png') top left;
}

#box-top-right {
position: absolute;
top: 75px;
right: -97px;
width: 400px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
text-align: center;
background: #ce180b;
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
color:white;
}

#wrapper {
width: 1200px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -50px;
 }
```

Comment: Code example is made

Comment: where is the rotated thingy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just put a container inside the body and set that to overflow:hidden;
Keep the rotated square within the container div.
Keep the width of the container at whatever you need,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rotated-thingy">
```

And css:

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;/* depends, maybe it could be stretched by something else? */
  overflow-x:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.rotated-thingy{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;/* or whatever appropriate here */
}
```

Sometimes elements html and body are not exactly treated the same way as the div's are.

Comment: When i add overflow:hidden to my container everything on the site dissapear, and without overflow:hidden its not making any different.

Comment: If you go overflow:hidden on the container, it needs to have it's height set manually. Maybe just go overflow-x: hidden then, updated my answer.

Comment: Changed the container height to 100vh, just to get height on it.
Now its working on my mobile(using chrome), except when i use android browser, then all the content is hidden, but im still able to click it.

Comment: Perhaps your version of android browser doesn't support vh? http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: didnt even Think about that. Thanks for the help.